# Laravel resources load in http, but not in https

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a subdomain that I have secured with a wildcard SSL that uses Laravel as the framework. When I load the main page on the subdomain, everything loads just fine, no issues, but when I change from http to https, none of the resources will load and I get a series of 503 errors saying that they are unavailable. Resources loaded from external sites, like bootstrap and Jquery load just fine, but local resources do not. Does anyone know what the issue could be? I am using Laravel 5.4 as well.

Comment: have you restarted your http server after installing ssl? validate an index.html with https first, also what does the error log say?

Answer (score 0):

Which host are you using
You might need to restart Apache or Nginx to made that change happen